# Replace similar strings in a file in place

Tags: regex, macos, shell, sed, grep

I have a file with the following types of pairs of strings:

```
Call Stack: [UniqueObject1] | [UnOb2] | [SuspectedObject1] | [SuspectedObject2] | [SuspectedObject3] |  [UnOb3] | [UnOb4] | [UnOb5] | ... end till unique objects

Call Stack: [UniqueObject1] | [UnOb2] | 0x28798765 | 0x18793765 | 0x48792767 |  [UnOb3] | [UnOb4] | [UnOb5] | ... end till unique objects
```

There are many such pairs that occur in the file.
The attributes of this pair are that the first part of the pair has "SuspectedObject1","SuspectedObject2" and so on, which in the second part of the pair are replaced by HEX-VALUES of the address of those objects.

What I want to do is, remove all the second part of the pairs.

Please note the pairs do not occur in any specific order and might be separated by many lines in between.

I plan to iterate through each line of this file, if I see a hex-string given as an address instead of a suspected object, I would want to start comparing the following regex

```
Call Stack: [UniqueObject1] | [UnOb2] | * | * | * |  [UnOb3] | [UnOb4] | [UnOb5] | ... end till unique objects
```

in the whole file and if a string does match, I want to remove this specific line from the file.

Can someone suggest a shell way to do this?

Comment: What do the object descriptions look like? Can they contain hex addresses? Can they contain | characters? Are the hex addresses always at column 3, 4 and 5 (with columns separated by |)? Can the non hex lines occur both before and after the hex line? Can there be more than one identical hex line? Do you want to remove the hex line(s) or the non hex line(s)?

Comment: 1. Object descriptions would only consist of [a-zA-z_] e.g UITableView_userSelectRowAtPendingSelectionIndexPath:showTable 2. No they will never have hex addresses 3. Yes the non-hex lines might occur before or after the hex lines. 4. No there would be only one identical hex line 5. I want to remove the hex line, but only if a similar non-hex line is availab.e

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your question correctly, you may need to use `awk`. Run like:

```
awk -f script.awk file file
```

Contents of `script.awk`:

```
BEGIN { 
    FS=" \\| "
}

FNR==NR {
    $3=$4=$5=""
    a[$0]++
    next
}

$3 ~ /^0x[0-9]{8}$/ {
    r=$0
    $3=$4=$5="" 
    if (a[$0]<2) { 
        print r
    }
    next
}1
```

Alternatively, here's the one-liner:

```
awk -F ' \\| ' 'FNR==NR { $3=$4=$5=""; a[$0]++; next } $3 ~ /^0x[0-9]{8}$/ { r=$0; $3=$4=$5=""; if (a[$0]<2) print r; next }1' file{,}
```

Comment: Also, you may need/want to adjust the regex to match the hex strings you're interested in. Please let me know how it goes. Cheers.